# How can a table in email using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I want to send a table by email using apps-script.

Here is the table:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function sendEmail()
{

  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: to,
  subject: subject,
  htmlBody: activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alerts Script').getRange("J8:M").getValues()
});
}
```

Here is the result, how can I stringy the table in a readable way?

[image]

I have tried

```
  subject: JSON.stringify(activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alerts Script').getRange("B4").getValue()),
```

And the result wasn't readable:

[image]

Comment: For example, as a simple modification, how about modifying `activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alerts Script').getRange("J8:M").getValues()` to `JSON.stringify(activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alerts Script').getRange("J8:M").getValues())`?

Comment: By the way, in your script, please remove `;` of `activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alerts Script').getRange("J8:M").getValues();`.

Comment: It didn't work out. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJt1K.png

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. For your situation, I proposed 2 patterns in an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is due to that the object is directly used. So how about the following modifications?

#### Pattern 1:

As a simple modification, `JSON.stringify()` can be used as follows.

```
htmlBody: JSON.stringify(activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alerts Script').getRange("J8:M").getValues())
```

or,

```
var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alerts Script');
var values = sheet.getRange("J8:M" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: to,
  subject: subject,
  htmlBody: JSON.stringify(values)
});
```

#### Pattern 2:

When you want to put the values as a HTML table, you can also use the following modification.

```
var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alerts Script');
var values = sheet.getRange("J8:M" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var html = values.reduce((s, e) => s += "<tr><td>" + e.join("</td><td>") + "</td>", "<table>") + "</table>";
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: to,
  subject: subject,
  htmlBody: html
});
```

#### References:

- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: BTW, `reduce((s, e) => s +` I assume `s` is the accumulator seed? where is it initialized to `""`.

Comment: @Elad Benda Thank you for replying. About the pattern 2, the initial value of `s` is `"<table>"` of `, "<table>")`. When this is modified to `, "")`, the top tab of `<table>` is not shown. If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.